# How to run TestU01 to test a random number generator

Tags: random, python-3.7

I have implemented random sequence generator in python and want to test the results in TestU01. But I am not getting how to give input for that test suite and also suggest me that how many bit sequence I need to generate to test the sequence

Answer (score 1):

TestU01 is a library and doesn't come with executables. It mostly has methods to test C generators which implement `unif01_Gen` defined in `unif01.h`. See `guideshorttest01.pdf`.

However, it does come with a few methods which test binary files. Here is a short program which calls them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "gdef.h"
#include "swrite.h"
#include "bbattery.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc != 2) {
       printf("Specify binary file of random bits as ./test <path>");
       return 0;
   }

   FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
   size_t sz = ftell(fp) * 8;
   fclose(fp);
   
   printf("Reading binary file %s of size %d bits", argv[1], sz);
   
   swrite_Basic = FALSE;
   bbattery_RabbitFile (argv[1], sz);
   bbattery_AlphabitFile (argv[1], sz);
   bbattery_FIPS_140_2File (argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

After installing TestU01 (it's in the Arch/Manjaro AUR, in case that helps), compile it with: `gcc test.c -o test -ltestu01`

Here is a Python program which generates a random binary file. Note that the tests work on 32-bit blocks, and I suggest to stick to that when generating the file.

```
size = 1024*1024
rand = Random()
with open("bits", "wb") as f:
  for i in range(size//4):
    value = rand.getrandbits(32)
    s = struct.pack('I', value)
    f.write(s)
```

There is also a version of SmallCrush which reads a text file of about 5 million floats. See `bbattery_SmallCrushFile`. I haven't tried it, but make sure the floats are written with many digits as the conversion to/from text can break the test.

I don't know much about the theory of testing RNGs, so I can't answer how long of a sequence you need. The TestU01 guide is detailed and might answer your questions.